# Optical Receivers and Amplifiers

Tags: photodiode, receiver, telecommunications, optical-fibre

I have been doing some past papers for a university module I am studying. I am not from an electrical engineering background so don’t really know how to attempt the question attached. I would really appreciate guidance in how to look at these questions.

Brief outline is using the responsivity of PIN diode and a transimpedance amplifier to determine the output voltage.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

In request, please see circuit diagram and workings. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Show your work up until the point you got stuck.

Comment: Hi, I basically converted the dBm power received to wattage, multiplied that by the responsivity of 0.8 A/W. That then gives me a photo current which I then multipled by the load resistor to get a voltage. I then converted the gain to a multiplier and times that voltage by the multiplier. I am not sure that is the right way to do it?

Comment: I effectively deemed the capacitance as irrelevant to the calculation? Not sure if that was the correct thing to do, as well as the bandwidth?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track.  _Edit your question_ with your answer so far -- if you feel comfortable using LaTeX, keep in mind that it's available to you: `\$ \int e^{at} dt =  e^{at} + C\$` renders as \$ \int e^{at} dt =  e^{at} + C\$.

Comment: Draw the circuit again with the components replaced with their equivalent resistors and capacitors!  We can tell you if you've got the circuit correct. Once you've got the logic correct, then we can construct the simple equations.

Comment: Please add the requested information to your question. Comments may be deleted by mods at any time.

Comment: Hint 1: Average power is not the same as peak power. Hint 2: You haven't actually been given the information needed to find the peak voltage --- you'll have to make some kind of assumption to get that answer.

Comment: Please see above my workings and diagram. Is there no way a peak power can be determined from the capacitance or multiply by sqrt(2) to get a peak power?

Comment: Hello, would be really appreciative for any guidance I have this exam tomorrow. Thanks.